# If $\sin(a+b)=1$ and $\sin(a-b)=\frac{1}{2}$ wher $a \geq 0$ and $b \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$ , find value of $\tan(a+2b)$ and $\tan(2a+b)$

Tags: trigonometry

If $\sin(a+b)=1$ and $\sin(a-b)=\frac{1}{2}$ where $a \geq 0$ and $b \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$ , find the value of $\tan(a+2b)$ and $\tan(2a+b)$.

I have tried to apply the formula for $\tan(a+(a+b))$ but couldn't reach anywhere.

THANKS

Comment: See here: http://m.meritnation.com/ask-answer/question/if-sin-a-b-1-and-sin-a-b-1-2-where-0-a-b-2/trigonometric-functions/2548531

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$$\sin(a + b) = 1$$

$$\sin(a + b) = \sin \frac π2$$

$$a + b = \frac π2 = 90^\circ$$

Also,

$$\sin(a - b) = \frac 12$$

$$\sin(a - b) = \sin \frac π6$$

$$a - b = \frac π6 = 30^\circ$$

Solve equations to find $a$, $b$.

$$a = \frac π3 = 60^\circ$$

$$b = \frac π6 = 30^\circ$$

Put values of $a$ and $b$ to solve.

Answer (score 1):

You can immediately determine that
$$a+b=\pi/2$$
$$a-b=\pi/6$$
So $a=\pi/3$ and $b=\pi/6$ and so you can calculate the required values directly.

Comment: why can't $a$ be greater than 60 degrees. they havenot specified quadrant to which a belongs

Comment: You can always just write $a+b= (\frac{\pi}{2} + 2\pi k)$ with $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ if that detail is truly required.